# Cannot install virtualbox on ubuntu 15.10

Tags: virtualbox, ubuntu-15.10, dkms

I operate according to https://gist.github.com/PartTimeLegend/5328700, But
I got the following error：

```
Loading new virtualbox-5.0.14 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 4.2.0-42-generic
Building initial module for 4.2.0-42-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 5.0.14_Ubuntu for vboxdrv.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 4.2.0-42-generic (5.1.2).
You may override by specifying --force.

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 5.0.14_Ubuntu for vboxnetadp.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 4.2.0-42-generic (5.1.2).
You may override by specifying --force.

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 5.0.14_Ubuntu for vboxnetflt.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 4.2.0-42-generic (5.1.2).
You may override by specifying --force.

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Error! Module version 5.0.14_Ubuntu for vboxpci.ko
is not newer than what is already found in kernel 4.2.0-42-generic (5.1.2).
You may override by specifying --force.

depmod.....

DKMS: install completed.

vboxweb.service is a disabled or a static unit, not starting it.
Job for virtualbox.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status virtualbox.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
```

`dmesg` found error:

```
[23970.809479] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
[24080.976410] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
[28028.539569] Request for unknown module key 'virtualbox: b2b55b754f3bb6a535be36ff514e9e174b01bfda' err -11
```

My virtualbox install log file:

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B9Z0DTPHWdIVVXk5VWQxcE5XQ2c

I googled a lot and tried alot but no solution till now. Would be nice if someone can help me here :)
Many thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you don't install the latest version from the VirtualBox download page[1]?  There is a deb package for Ubuntu 15.10 (though you might consider upgrading to 16.04 LTS or the current non-LTS).  Full source is published for the binaries in the package.  Out of interest, which package is providing those kernel modules[2]?  [1] https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads [2] "dlocate vboxdrv.ko" on the command line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04 by disabling UEFI Secure Boot on my BIOS Setup menu. Then I just fully removed virtuabox then I just installed and n

Answer (score -1):

Yes, n3uron3 is right, I added some more details to the convenience of people's needs. **My PC brand is Acer, and must set a password in BOIS to disable UEFI Secure Boot, otherwise disable the UEFI Secure Boot option is gray(unavailability state)**. After the complete uninstall virtualbox and then re-install, you can use. Hope to help to everyone.